# WPF, button inheriting Foreground for its content

Tags: wpf, wpf-style

The problem: **how can I design button, which inherits `Foreground` from its parent, but allows changing it via style?**

More precisely, given following button:

```
<StackPanel TextBlock.Foreground="Red">
<ToggleButton Width="16" Height="16" FontSize="10" Style="{StaticResource ...}">
    <Grid>
        <Path Width="8" Height="8" Fill="...">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry Figures="M 1 0 L 1 4 L 0 4 L 0 5 L 3 5 L 3 8 L 4 8 L 4 5 L 7 5 L 7 4 L 6 4 L 6 0 L 1 0 z M 2 1 L 4 1 L 4 4 L 2 4 L 2 1 z " FillRule="NonZero"/>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </Grid>
</ToggleButton>
</StackPanel>
```

I need, that:

- Path's fill color matches StackPanel's current Foreground color, and
- When user hovers mouse over the button, path's fill color becomes some specific, constant color.

I tried designing style for button, including the `ControlTemplate`, but there's a problem with `Foreground`. Button has its `Foreground` property set to some `DynamicResource` via theme, so it doesn't match `StackPanel`'s `Foreground`.

Obviously I can bind it, but then style and control template triggers stops working, because I've set an immediate value to a dependency property, what overrules all other means of providing value to it.

To give a context to the problem, this is what I want to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Since when does a `StackPanel` has a `Foreground` property?

Comment: Attached - TextBlock.Foreground.

Answer (score 1):

You could bind to the attached `TextBlock.Foreground` of the `ToggleButton`'s parent `Panel` like this:

```
<Path Width="8" Height="8"
       Fill="{Binding (TextBlock.Foreground), 
           RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Panel, AncestorLevel=2}}">
...
```

If you want the `Fill` to change on mouse over, you could define a `Style` with a `DataTrigger`:

```
<StackPanel TextBlock.Foreground="Red">
    <ToggleButton Width="16" Height="16" FontSize="10">
        <Grid>
            <Path Width="8" Height="8">
                <Path.Data>
                    <PathGeometry Figures="M 1 0 L 1 4 L 0 4 L 0 5 L 3 5 L 3 8 L 4 8 L 4 5 L 7 5 L 7 4 L 6 4 L 6 0 L 1 0 z M 2 1 L 4 1 L 4 4 L 2 4 L 2 1 z "
                                  FillRule="NonZero"/>
                </Path.Data>
                <Path.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Path">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{Binding (TextBlock.Foreground), 
                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Panel, AncestorLevel=2}}" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, 
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ToggleButton}}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Blue" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Path.Style>
            </Path>
        </Grid>
    </ToggleButton>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by myself - I forgot, that style setters may set bindings as well. The solution is following.

Style:

```
<Style TargetType="ButtonBase" x:Key="DocumentTabButtonStyle">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=(TextBlock.Foreground), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=StackPanel}}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            ...                
        </Setter>
    </Style.Setters>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DocumentButtonHoverForegroundBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Button:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource DocumentTabButtonStyle}">
    <Path Fill="{Binding Path=(TextBlock.Foreground), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry Figures="M 0 1 L 3 4 L 0 7 L 2 7 L 4 5 L 6 7 L 8 7 L 5 4 L 8 1 L 6 1 L 4 3 L 2 1 Z" />
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</Button>
```